# error: column "..." of relation "..." does not exist

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using PostgreSQL with Sequelize in Nodejs.
There are 3 tables: `tc_user_intervention`, `tc_interventions` and `tc_users`.
`tc_user_intervention` has 2 fields: `userid` (from `tc_users`) and `interventionid` (from `tc_interventions`).
Here's the Sequelize model (auto-generated from the existing database):

```
const UserIntervention =  sequelize.define('tc_user_intervention', {
    userid: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'tc_users',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    interventionid: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'tc_interventions',
        key: 'id'
      }
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'tc_user_intervention',
    schema: 'public',
    timestamps: false
  });
```

If I try to do a raw query, everything works, I can insert a new raw into `tc_user_interventions`:

```
INSERT INTO `tc_user_intervention`
VALUES (value1, value2);
```

But if I try to do the same query with Sequelize, I receive the error:

```
 error: column "id" of relation "tc_user_intervention" does not exist
```

The query simply is:

```
UserIntervention.create({ 'userid': user, 'interventionid': intervention});
```

But Sequelize translate this query into:

```
sql:
      'INSERT INTO "public"."tc_user_intervention" ("id","userid","interventionid") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2) RETURNING "id","userid","interventionid";',
```

and obviously this give me the error, because the id column does not exist neither in the model nor in the database. Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/legacy/#primary-keys)? Sequelize expects an `id` (or otherwise specified primary key record) so you might need to use `Model.removeAttribute('id');` though this is not recommended. Also I recommend looking into the way Sequelize handles associations (see the sidebar in the linked documentation page).

Comment: Alternatively, you can add `primaryKey: true` to both `userid` and `interventionid` and this will work as a compound primary key. Give it a try. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much, adding primaryKey: true it doesn't work...but with model.removeAttribute('id') everything works